# How can i edit a value from mysql database from android studio using java + php script?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I tried to edit a value from a mysql database(from "addfav" column), when a star(imageView) is pressed. My database contains: "id, devicename, category, image, addfav" columns.

I have a recyclerview with some devices retrieved from database and every device had a star(for add to favorites) and when this star is pressed, i want that a value from "addfav" column from database to change.

For this, i used HashMap in OnBindViewHolder method, when the star is pressed, but this is not working and an error occurs.

The error:

```
11-30 15:49:16.584 14907-14907/com.example.photosib E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.photosib, PID: 14907
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.photosib.MainHomeActivity.HomeActivity cannot be cast to com.kosalgeek.asynctask.AsyncResponse
        at com.example.photosib.MainHomeActivity.Home.HomeRecyclerViewAdapter$2.onClick(HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.java:87)
```

My recyclelrview/adapter code:

```
public class HomeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private static final String URL_UPDATE = "php script";
private Context mCtx;
private List<HomeItemDevicesDetails> devicesList;
private HomeItemDevicesDetails addStarFav;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mCtx, List<HomeItemDevicesDetails> devicesList, SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.devicesList = devicesList;
    this.swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout;
}

@Override
public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_recyclerview_items, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final HomeItemDevicesDetails category = devicesList.get(position);
    //loading the image
    Glide.with(mCtx)
            .load(category.getImage())
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(category.getDevice_name());
    holder.textViewCategory.setText(category.getCategory());
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            HomeRefresh();
        }
    });
    // add to fav star
    holder.imageViewFavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.imageViewFavorites.getColorFilter() != null) {

                holder.imageViewFavorites.clearColorFilter();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Removed from Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                holder.imageViewFavorites.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mCtx,
                        R.color.orange));

                // here i tried to open and to execute the php file 

                HashMap addToFav = new HashMap();
                addToFav.put("id", category.getId());

                PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask((AsyncResponse) mCtx, addToFav);
                task.execute(URL_UPDATE);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Added to Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return devicesList.size();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewTitle, textViewCategory;
    ImageView imageView, imageViewFavorites;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_item_title);
        textViewCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_single_item_category);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_home_item);
        imageViewFavorites = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_favorites);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_single_item_details);

        parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // OPEN WHEN CLICK ON HOME ITEMS
                HomeActivity activity = (HomeActivity) view.getContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new SingleDeviceDetailsFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

    }
}

public void HomeRefresh()
{
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Collections.shuffle(devicesList);
            HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    },1500);
}
```

My fragment code, where the recyclerview is call(this works fine, not errors):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

    //this is the JSON Data URL
    //make sure you are using the correct ip else it will not work
    private static final String URL_CATEGORIES = "php script";

    //a list to store all the product
    List<HomeItemDevicesDetails> devicesList;

    //the recyclerview
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    // Home refresh
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        devicesList = new ArrayList<>();

        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview_row);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiper);

        //this method will fetch and parse json
        //to display it in recyclerview
        loadProducts();

        return view;
    }

    private void loadProducts() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_CATEGORIES,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject category = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                devicesList.add(new HomeItemDevicesDetails(
                                        category.getInt("id"),
                                        category.getString("device_name"),
                                        category.getString("category"),
                                        category.getString("url")
                                ));

                            }

                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            HomeRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(),devicesList, swipeRefreshLayout);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

The device model(here i am not sure if i need to retrieve the "addfav" value from database):

```
public class HomeItemDevicesDetails {

    private int id;
    private String device_name;
    private String category;
    private String image;

    public HomeItemDevicesDetails(int id, String device_name, String category, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.device_name = device_name;
        this.category = category;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDevice_name() {
        return device_name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

The php script for update the value from database:

```
<?php
$host = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$db = "xxxxxxx";


$id = $_GET['id'];

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE devices SET devices.addfav='1' WHERE devices.id='$id'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I don't know how to get through this problem. I'm not experienced in Java(i start with the Java development 3 months ago). Can someone give me some solutions/hints?

Comment: Is there any error repoted by PHP? Always debug your scripts with enabled [PHP Error Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)!

Comment: I did not check for errors with this method you recommend, but the php script seems to work ok. He returns me "Record updated successfully" when i call the script in browser